# when background service start a thread,the thread can't be stopped by system even if I press power key

Tags: android, linux

I have a little misunderstood about the powermanagement about android system.I know that if I keep a wakelock in my application,then the mobile won't sleep until I release the wakelock.But I have a anthor question,If I start a service from activity,then I start a background thread in service.when I press the power key,the mobile should go to sleep,in order to save power,but I find that the thread still run at background,so I am a little misunderstood,who prevent the android system from sleeping?

Comment: In other words，I really want to know how android system or linux system control mobile or cpu enter into power saver mode or sleep mode?so I can establish a socket long connection or background thread,I alway think when cpu or moible enter power saver or sleep mode,my appliction code won't be excuted until it is waked up.

Answer (score 0):

The android system doesnt goto sleep and it cannot gotto a "sleep" mode as it needs to handle numerous things like, SMS, Phones, Location, Alarm and other events like shake, gesture.

When you press the power button, just the screen is turned off and moves to a power saver mode. Rest everything is the same.

your thread will be run as long as the process is running or it has completed performing its task.

Comment: Cool,I am a little understand,can you give some details about power saver mode? And why android system has "wake up concept"？Does cpu will handle thread running even if the mobile enter power save mode?And what will wake up if the mobile return from power save mode?Thanks

Comment: By the way,when the cpu enter sleep mode?And will it keep on handling my background thread?